# Prove $\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{A-f(x)}}dx$ is finite for $f'(x_1)\neq0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

> For a smooth function $f$, with $f(x_1)=A$ and
>   $f(x)<A$ on $[x_0,x_1)$.
>
> Show that if $f'(x_1)\neq0$, than,
>
> $$\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{A-f(x)}}dx<\infty.$$

Since $f$ is smooth, we know that there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $f$ is strictly monotonic and $f'$ is positive on $[x_1-\delta,x_1]$, therefore we have,

\begin{align}
\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{A-f(x)}}dx&=\int_{x_0}^{x_1-\delta}\frac{1}{\sqrt{A-f(x)}}dx+\int_{x_1-\delta}^{x_1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{A-f(x)}}dx\\
&=C+\int_{f(x_1-\delta)}^A\frac{1}{\sqrt{A-u}}\cdot\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(u))}du.
\end{align}

For some finite constant $C$ and substitution on the second integral by $u=f(x)$.

Now since $f'$ is positive on $[x_1-\delta,x_1]$ (a compact set), it achieves a lower bound $\varepsilon>0$.

Therefore we may bound the above expression by,

\begin{align}
C+\int_{f(x_1-\delta)}^A\frac{1}{\sqrt{A-u}}\cdot\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(u))}du&\leq C+\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{f(x_1-\delta)}^A\frac{1}{\sqrt{A-u}}du\\
&=C+\frac{2}{\varepsilon}\sqrt{A-f(x_1-\delta)}<\infty.
\end{align}

Could someone please look over my work to make sure my proof is correct.

Also, is there a simpler way to prove this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can write $$A-f(x)=(x_1-x)\left(f'(x_1)+\varepsilon(x)\right)\qquad (*)$$ with $x\mapsto \varepsilon(x) $  a continous function on $[x_0,x_1)$ and  $\lim_{x\to x_1}\varepsilon(x)=0$.

From $(*)$ we  can see that $f'(x_1)>0$, and then by continuity of $\varepsilon$, we have $$A-f(x)>(x_1-x)\frac{f'(x_1)}{2}$$
for all $x\in [x_1-\delta,x_1)$ for some $\delta>0$.

Comment: Could you maybe re-post your binomial identity from yesterday? I think I can prove it.